# Extra space in bottom tab navigation - React navigation

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, bottomnavigationview, react-navigation-bottom-tab

just updated to latest version of `@react-navigation/bottom-tabs` and i am getting this weird space under the items on iphone .[image]

here is the [snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@adnanashraf/bottom-tab-extra-space-)

Answer (score 0):

The space is the part of [iOS safe area](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/layout#iOS-iPadOS-safe-areas). By default the area is detected. Use [safeAreaInsets](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/5.x/bottom-tab-navigator/#safeareainsets) to override this behaviour. Something like this:

```
<Tab.Navigator
...
  tabBarOptions={{
    safeAreaInsets: {bottom: ?}
  }}
>
...
</Tab.Navigator>
```

Or another option is to set the background color to cover the safe area. Something like this:

```
<Tab.Navigator
  tabBarOptions={{
    style: {
      backgroundColor: ?,
    },
  }}
>
...
</Tab.Navigator>
```